# Configure WCF host for windows integrated security

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I have WCF service hosted on IIS7.5 running as anonymous - authentication, Please let me know the configuration/steps to run on windows integrated security. Thanks

Comment: The WCF configuration steps, or the IIS steps, or both? What bindings are you using?

Comment: please provide both. using Net tcp binding.

Comment: sorry i am using basic http, i have to change that to net tcp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the nice thing about [NetTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx) is that it is secured using Transport security, Windows authentication by default. So all you need to do is use it. Your server binding would look something like this:

```
<service name="YourServiceNameHere">
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://machineName/VirtualDirectory/"/>
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>

  <endpoint
    address=""
    binding="netTcpBinding"
    contract="YourServiceContractHere" />
</service>
```

[Here is an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733089.aspx) that goes more in depth. In IIS, you need to [enable net.tcp](http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2010/10/08/setting-up-a-nettcpbinding-enabled-wcf-service-in-iis-7.aspx), and enable Windows authentication.

[image: IIS screenshot]