# Web service calling user is always anonymous

Tags: web-services, wcf, windows-authentication

I have a simple web service written using WCF. I'm trying to get the details of the caller so I can check their details. I'm doing it like this:

```
var ident = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity;
```

However, it's coming back as empty and

```
bool isAnon = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.IsAnonymous;
```

is returning true.

How do I get the details? I thought if, in the client I added this to the config:

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

to my basicHttpBinding it would do this.

What am I missing? I've been struggling trying to do any kind of authorisation working. This programmatic approach was because I simply failed to get WIA working through IIS.

I tried Current.WindowsIdentity and that was blank too.

Comment: You will need to configure IIS, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358299/configure-wcf-host-for-windows-integrated-security

Comment: Thanks, I tried that (disable anonymous, enable windows) but all I got was 'the requested service xxx could not be activated' when I tried

Comment: The error is it says the authentication schemes configured on the host 'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication' do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding (Anonymous)' please ensure that the securitymode is set to transport.

But as above, it is set to transport.